# Open file dialog with fixed dialog formborder style

Tags: file, dialog

I want to open file dialog in window application, but that file dialog should not be re-sizable, means that dialog can't re-size just as a fixed dialog.
I have attached an images, want to remove re-sizable that is in red circle...
I am using C#.net

[image: Open file dialog]

Comment: What language/platform/environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do that. Simply because this is a behavior a normal windows user wouldn't expect and what would be your benefit if this would be possible (against the drawbacks the user has to take into account)?